# C#: How to keep the global variable not changed when passed to a function?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, onenote

I am developing an add-in for OneNote.
In the sinppet below, a global variable `AllPageXML` is claimed first.
Then the very first time when a window is loaded, `AllPageXML` is initinized with a value.
After that, the value of `AllPageXML` is supposed to not be changed.
When the user input some keywords in a textbox, search in `AllPageXML` will be excuted.
And `AllPageXML`  will be passed to an function `FilterXml`.  After returnning, the value of `AllPageXML` has been changed.
How can I do to keep the value of `AllPageXML` not changed? Any comments will be appreciated.

```cs
    internal partial class NaviPages : LocalizableForm
    {
        public XElement AllPageXML;
        public NaviPages()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            using var one = new OneNote();
            var AllPageXML = one.GetAllPages();
            //...//

        }
        
        private void tBoxKw_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string strKeyWords = tBoxKw.Text.ToLower();
                FilteredPageXml = FilterXml(AllPageXML, strKeyWords);           
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to filter!");
            }
        }
         public XElement FilterXml(XElement inXML, string strKeyWords)
        {
            string strSecKw, strPageKw;
            XElement root = inXML;
            ///...///
            //delete empty notebook
            foreach (var child1 in root.Elements().Reverse())
            {
                if (!child1.HasElements) child1.Remove();
            }
            return root;
        }

    }
```

Also, I've tried to use the `ICloneable` class to clone the `AllPageXML` before using it.

```cs
namespace OneNoteAddIn
{
    internal partial class NaviPages : LocalizableForm
    {
        public NaviPages()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public MyPages xml1;
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            using var one = new OneNote();
            xml1= new MyPages();
            xml1.AllPageXML= one.GetAllPages();   
        }


        public XElement FilterXml(XElement inXML, string strKeyWords)
        {
            XElement root = inXML; // xml2.AllPageXML;
            //delete empty notebook
            foreach (var child1 in root.Elements().Reverse())
            {
                if (!child1.HasElements) child1.Remove();
            }
            return root;
        }

             
        private void tBoxKw_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XElement FilteredPageXml;
            MyPages xml2 = new MyPages();
            xml2 = (MyPages)xml1.Clone();
            XElement AllPageXML1 = xml2.AllPageXML;
            try
            {
                string strKeyWords = tBoxKw.Text.ToLower();
    
                    FilteredPageXml = FilterXml(AllPageXML1, strKeyWords);      
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to filter!");
            }
        }


    }
    class MyPages : ICloneable
    {
        public XElement AllPageXML;
        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Either mark your variable as const, which gets baked in at the compile time or mark it as readonly, which can be changed once in a constructor i guess and not any further, any attempt to change leads to an error at compile or runtime.
Some reference 
https://exceptionnotfound.net/const-vs-static-vs-readonly-in-c-sharp-applications/

Comment: Since `FilterXml` is modiying the `inXML` object, you can pass it a clone of your `AllPageXML` member (or alternatively change `FilterXml` to clone `inXML` before operating on it).

Comment: Still not much luck here, even if I treid to clone one.

Answer (score 2):

The line `XElement root = inXML;` does not create a new object, it only sets the reference of `root` to the same reference `inXML` uses. So any changes to `root` or `inXML` will change the same object in memory. You should instead clone the object (create a new one with the same values). This can be done in 2 places.

1. In the `FilterXml` method.
2. In `tBoxKw_TextChanged` before `FilterXml` is called and pass `FilterXml` the clone.

To clone an object you should create a new object (using `new XElement()`) and set the properties of that element to the values of properties of the object you wish to clone (`AllPageXML`). You could look into the `ICloneable` interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable.clone?view=net-7.0

Comment: Could you help to check my 2nd snippet I posted above? It still does not work. If any direct examples can be shown, it would be highly appreciated.